# Loss over pixels

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, backpropagation, gradient-descent

During backpropagation, will these cases have different effect:-

1. sum up loss over all pixels then backpropagate.
2. average loss over all pixels then backpropagate
3. backpropagate individuallyover all pixels.

My main doubts in regarding the numerical value but the effect all these would be having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between no 1 and 2 is basically : since `sum` will result in bigger than `mean`, the magnitude of gradients from `sum` operation will be bigger, but direction will be same.

Here's a little demonstration, lets first declare necessary variables:

```
x = torch.tensor([4,1,3,7],dtype=torch.float32,requires_grad=True)
target = torch.tensor([4,2,5,4],dtype=torch.float32)
```

Now lets compute gradient for `x` using `L2` loss with `sum`:

```
loss = ((x-target)**2).sum()
loss.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

This outputs: `tensor([ 0., -2., -4.,  6.])`

Now using `mean`: (after resetting `x` grad)

```
loss = ((x-target)**2).mean()
loss.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

And this outputs: `tensor([ 0.0000, -0.5000, -1.0000,  1.5000])`
Notice how later gradients are exactly 1/4th of that of `sum`, that's because the tensors here contain 4 elements.

About third option, if I understand you correctly, that's not possible. You can not backpropagate before aggregating individual pixel errors to a scalar, using `sum`, `mean` or anything else.